# getNodeValue returnining null?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to parse and XML file from an url, my NodeList contains values but getNodeValue for each node returns null. Can anybody help me?

This is my method where I parse the xml.

```
public ArrayList xmloku(String url) {

        ArrayList xmllistesi = new ArrayList();

        try {

            URL xmlyolu = new URL(url);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(xmlyolu
                    .openStream()));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeListCountry = document
                    .getElementsByTagName("karikatur");

            for (int i = konum; i < nodeListCountry.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeListCountry.item(i);
                Element elementMain = (Element) node;
                xmllistesi.add(elementMain.getNodeValue());
                     }
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? Post your XML please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `getNodeValue()` try using `getTextContent()`

```
for (int i = konum; i < nodeListCountry.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeListCountry.item(i);
    Element elementMain = (Element) node;
    xmllistesi.add(elementMain.getTextContent());
}
```